# T-SQL select date withing 30 days range

Tags: sql-server

I would like to select all the rows with dates between 30 days range from today,

so between 22-04-2022 till 22-05-2022,

I've tried

```
SELECT DATEXP, ID FROM TABLE
where DATEXP > cast(getdate() + 30 as date) and DATEXP <= cast(getdate() as date)
```

but this doesn't seem to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `DATEADD()` function here:

```sql
SELECT DATEXP, ID
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATEXP >= GETDATE() AND DATEXP < DATEADD(day, 30, GETDATE());
```

Also note that your inequality was incorrect.  You should have the earlier date on the left GTE comparison and the later date on the right LT comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition seems to be wrong, you are expecting the date to be `>= Today + 30` days BUT less than today.

So if for example.

Today is `22 April 2022`

Today + 30 = `22 May 2022`

If I have a date `DATEXP`  say `23 May 2022`, it can't be `>= 22 May 2022` and LESS then `22 April 2022` at the same time.

Maybe you want the Condition to be `>= Today AND < Today + 30`?